# nrjavaserial and permission to /var/lock (link to /run/lock)

Tags: java, linux, serial-port, locking

I have problem with using nrjavaserial on CentOS / Red Hat 7.x on standard user account.
Opening COMx port (/dev/ttySx) creates lock in /var/lock, but /var/lock is just a link to /run/lock which (after every reboot) has root owner & permissions.

I found two solutions:

1. Modify C/C++/Java sources and change default lock directory (to /tmp/lock)
2. Change group permission of /run/lock on every boot (to dialout group with read/write permission)

Which way is better and how to do it properly?

PS standard user is in dialout group.

Answer (score 1):

Typically due to legacy reasons applications will create a lock file inside /var/lock directory. Two applications will not access serial port at same time only if both uses locking scheme. Option 1 may not work as other application will look for lock in /var/lock directory. Option 2 is also not good idea as it will other issues. See this file in nrjavaserial source code src/main/c/include/SerialImp.h

The directory /var or /run are part of standard root file system and every time you reboot init.rc script will override whatever you do. Please describe why is this locking problem for you.

Comment: The problem is with nrjavaserial - it doesn't work in Red Hat 7.0 due to locking issue. I have to do sth to make it work. Now I know only two options (and there is no other option):

 1. Change locking dir in C sources to /var/lock/lockdev (new, the best path for tty* locks)
 
 or
 
 2.  Make /run/lock accesible to lock group (modify /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/legacy.conf file)
 
 or
 ?

Comment: Correct option would be to either modify the nrjavaserial to remove locking part or try some other library like serialpundit etc.

Comment: I looked over nrjavaserial code, especially C/C++ part (the source of *.dll i *.so libraries). Windows and Linux C code is full of bugs - it should not work under Windows x64! I made some changes in C code and now *.so & *.dll libraries work better, but full code must be reviewd. I don't recommend using nrjavaserial in Windows x64 or CentOS-like evironment. Is there any alternatives to nrjavaserial that work in x64 Windows and CentOS? Serialpundit is too complicated and supports "Windows 7 or later". Why? - Programming COM ports in Windows XP or Windows 10 use the same API functions.

Comment: Fazacast/Jssc are some other libraries that you may try. SerialPundit looks little complicated at first because of so many features but eventually may be useful. Consider fazecast on github also.